# Shared Configuration and AppSettings

Tags: iis, web-config, iis-7.5

We use Shared Configuration for our IIS config, so the same config is used by the webservers. This works well.

We like to share some server-level `<AppSettings>` between the servers. (in IIS manager, select Server -> Application Settings) Will the `<AppSettings>` on server level are also shared with the Shared Configuration?

I can't find the `<AppSettings>` in applicationHost.config nor administration.config, so I think it won't be shared, but I also don't know where those server-level appsettings will be stored.

Comment: `appSettings` are inherited from applicationHost.config (fortunately none are defined!) so it should work.

Comment: Strange as I defined them in iis manager on the root level, there are applied on every website (tested that), but I can't find them in applicationHost.config